# Jeppesen airport codes for holding positions - catstops

Tags: aeronautical-charts, airport-design, jeppesen

what would be the meaning of the jeppesen catstop codes for holding positions(AM_TaxiwayHoldingPosition):
{-32767, -32765, 2, 1} ?
Seems that they are used completly different, for example on LTFM (Istanbul Airport).
location in the photo: 41.26710012, 28.72905103
[image]

Comment: I would be *very very very* suspicious of any number which happens to be $0-(2^{15}-1)$. [Very](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) [suspicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 0):

`AM_TaxiwayHoldingPosition` is a [*feature class*](https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/extensions/aviation-charting/mapping-information-for-amdb-and-airports.htm) in the [Aerodrome mapping database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodrome_mapping_database), a geographic information system defined by two US and EU based aviation standardisation organizations.

[According to Eurocontrol](https://www.eurocontrol.int/service/aerodrome-mapping), information in this database is encoded using the [Aerodrome Mapping Exchange Model (AMXM)](https://www.amxm.aero/). [The schema for this model is available on the AMXM website](http://www.amxm.aero/schema/2.0.0/amxm.xsd) ([compare also interactive view here](https://www.aixm.aero/sites/aixm.aero/files/imce/AIXM51HTML/AIXM/Class_TaxiHoldingPosition.html). Under

```
<element name="TaxiwayHoldingPosition" (...)
```

we find

```
<element name="catstop" type="amxm:catstopTypeType">
<annotation>
<documentation>Definition: Low visibility operation category of holding position.</documentation>
</annotation>
```

While this does not answer your question (which is not entirely clear to me), it might give you guidance as to where to look for answers.

Perhaps it would be helpful if you added the documentation for the format of `AM_TaxiwayHoldingPosition: {-32767, -32765, 2, 1}`. 
Which of these is supposed to be runway category [("CATSTOP")](https://www.datacat.aero/showpropsub.php/?id=258)?

Comment: My question is what those values for catstops means.

Comment: Where did you get those values from? Surely there must be some schema/format documentation in whatever document you took this from?